# Logica de incrementar posição com php para o html

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho esse comando.

PHP

```
$id = 0;
$i = 0;
$vali = true;
$top1 = 0;
$top2 = 20;
$px = 'px';

$query = "select * from software where userid = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$quantia = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i; $i< $quantia; $i++){
    $dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['teste'] = $dado["itens"];
    if($vali == true){
        echo "<div class='ts'> <style type='text/css'>.ts{top:$top1$px}</style>";
        echo $_SESSION['teste'];
        echo "</div>";
        $vali = false;
        $top1 += 20;
        
    }else{
        echo "<div class='ts2'> <style type='text/css'>.ts2{top:$top2$px}</style>";
        echo $_SESSION['teste'];
        echo "</div>";
        $vali = true;
        $top2 += 20;
    }
    
}
```

CSS

```
#section .section div .itens .ts{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
#section .section div .itens .ts2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(144, 184, 184);
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;

}
```

HTML

```
<section id="section">
        <div class="section">
            <div>
                <div class="itens">
                        <?php include 'itens.php'?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

A logica parece está certa, minha ideia é que dependendo da quantidade de itens que tenha no meu Banco de dados, vá criando divs e jogando para baixo com css( top:20px ), mas todos acabam ficando na mesma posição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As divs são criadas corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

OBS, não é 20px, em sim 40px.
Já arrumei isso.

Answer (score 0):

Não use `position: absolute` isso faz os elementos se sobreporem, precisaria definir manualmente a posição de cada um, o que além de ruim fica mais difícil quando não se sabe quantos itens tem, use `display: inline-block` para fazer cada div ocupar toda a linha e ficarem um abaixo do outro:

```css
div.itens {
  display: block;
}

#section .section div .itens .ts{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px
}

#section .section div .itens .ts1{
     background-color: aqua;
 }

#section .section div .itens .ts2{
    background-color: rgb(144, 184, 184);
}
```

```html
<section id="section">
        <div class="section">
            <div>
                <div class="itens">
                  <div class='ts ts1'>teste1</div>
                  <div class='ts ts2'>teste2</div>
                  <div class='ts ts2'>teste3</div>
                  <div class='ts ts2'>teste4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Adicionei uma margem para ficar visualmente mais fácil de ver o resultado, e para evitar o código duplicado, coloquei os estilos em comum na class "ts" e só a cor em "ts1" e "ts2"